# Start storyboard UIViewController from from UIController

Tags: xcode, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

HI i have UIViewController. It has some array. After 3 seconds i am instantiating  storyboard and finding first UIViewController in storyboard and setting my data for new UIViewController. My Code is as follows:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBar", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_bar_story") as! UITabBarController

        let uiControllers:[UIViewController] = tabBarController.viewControllers!

        print("Size \(uiControllers.count)")

        var controller = uiControllers[0] as! UserTabBarItemViewController
        controller.users = self.users

//        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When self.present line is uncommented i am getting following error.

```
Size 2
2016-12-13 23:53:16.684 swift_mvp[4229:87787] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <swift_mvp.ViewController: 0x7fb8eef02e20>.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

My New tabBar in new Storyboard has 2 UIViewControllers i mean tabs. Is there something i am doing worng here.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to pass data i had to use:

```
self.present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

instead of first view controller.